# Erro no modulo Python-docx no Windows

Tags: python, windows, biblioteca

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
from docx import Document
d = Document(open("arquivo.docx"))
```

Esse código funciona no Ubuntu mas não funciona no windows.

No windows tenho o retorno no terminal:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Default2.py", line 94, in dialogo
>       d = Document(f)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\api.py", line 35, in **init**
>       document_part, package = self._open(docx)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\api.py", line 193, in _open
>       package = Package.open(docx)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 116, in open
>       pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgreader.py", line 32, in from_f
>   ile
>
> phys_reader = PhysPkgReader(pkg_file)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 101, in __init
>   __
>       self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'r')
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 793, in **init**
>       self._RealGetContents()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 860, in _RealGetContents
>       raise BadZipfile("Truncated central directory")
>   zipfile.BadZipfile: Truncated central directory

O código completo está [nesse link](http://pastebin.com/DfP1Cca6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a solução do erro gerado usei o seguinte código na linha 93:

```
f = open(arquivo,'rb')
```

"rb" Reads Binary. Para saber mais acesse o [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) da biblioteca

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar assim na linha 93:

```
f = open(arquivo,'w')
```

ou ao invés do `w`, coloque `r+`. Pois o `w` é para criar um novo arquivo ou sobreescrever ele, e o `r+` é para leitura e inserção de dados.

Comment: @Math a resposta dele me ajudou bastante. Porem não era a correta, mas me da caminhos por onde devo continuar pesquisando. De qualquer forma alterei para a forma que serviu para min. Obrigado.

Comment: @MuriloFerro você pode postar sua própria resposta explicando o que fez para resolver, se achar que convém explicar.

Comment: Excelente resposta.